# Finding lcm from 1 through 20, gives error "at Main.gcd(Main.java:21)"

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the lcm of numbers (1,2,3,4....20), this is a very simple java program to do so but it gives me an error. This error only appears when i run the loop to 20, but not when i run it till 10. The answer is 232792560 which is a 9 digit number, which should easily come in long data type so i doubt its an overflow problem. I cannot find the bug, please help.

```
static long gcd(long a, long b)
{
    if(a==b) return a;

    if(a>b)
    {
        return gcd(a-b , b);
    }
    else{
        return gcd(a, b-a);
    }
}

static long lcm(long a, long b)
{
    return (a*b)/gcd(a, b);
}   

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long l=1;
    for(long i=1;i<=20;i++)
    {
        l=lcm(l , i);
        System.out.println(l);
    }           
}
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: If you mention what error you get you will increase a lot your chances of getting help. Even better if you post the stacktrace.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a stack overflow. Your recursive algorithm for finding the gcd will result in a lot of calls.

Comment: Yeah, it does seem to be that, the error is just a repeated "at Main.gcd(Main.java:21)" ad infinitum. The thought of stack overflow did not come to mind as i was under the impression this already was euclids algo(and it kinda is just a really inefficient one) and would be fast enough. Thanks, feel silly now that i know whats wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive algorithm for calculating the gcd results in a stack overflow. Running the same algorithm (on python to test it quickly), gives the lcm of 1-14 as 360360. To find the gcd of this and 15 results in 360360/15 recursive calls (~24,000) which Java can't handle.

You need to find a non-recursive way of finding the gcd (or at least a more efficient one).

Have a look at [the euclidean algorithm](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/the-euclidean-algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

As Holloway stated. For gcd you can use:

```
public static long gcd(long P, long Q) {
        if (P % Q == 0) {
            return Q;
        } else {
            return gcd(Q, P % Q);
        }
    }
```